# Custom ProgressMonitorDialog class

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

Can I have a code snippet where the class ProgressMonitorDialog.java is extended. I have a requirement where a piece of code is executed under the ProgressMonitorDialog.java class (in its operation class) but the dialog should not be disposed after the immediately after, instead it must be in some other part of the code that cannot be included there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the dialog being closed at the end of the `run` call override the `finishedRun` method.

The standard `finishedRun` method is:

```java
protected void finishedRun() {
    decrementNestingDepth();
    close();
}
```

if you leave out the `close()` call the dialog will stay open.

Comment: I have done the same, just added a check which I am handling somewhere else and   then call the finishedRun method. 
If I again check the reference variable the shell is disposed but few variables hold some values.
Will this affect the performance.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question

Comment: I have the reference to my custom ProgressDialog class in another class where I intend to dispose of the Dialog. After disposing it off once when I check the reference the shell is disposed but there are somethings still left. So will this affect my application performance since somethings are still left.

Comment: It is impossible to answer that because I don't know what the 'somethings still left' are. If the shell is disposed then the dialog won't be used graphics resources anymore.

Comment: When I meant somethings it was some variables like block ,message etc. I wanted to be double sure before implementing it.

Comment: If you still have a reference to the dialog the variables will still be using memory. But this isn't likely to important.